# How do you put two Views in a horizontal Layout so that one is aligned to the left and the other one - to the right?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface

Let's say you want to have a TextView and a Button in a Layout with horizontal orientation. Can you have the TextView aligned to the left and the Button - to the right?

```
---------------------
TextView       Button
---------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout) and position the second view to right.

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstView"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/firstView"
```

Answer (score 4):

1) Use a RelativeLayout and android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" on one and android:layout_alignParentRight="true" on the other.

2) Use  a LinearLayout with android:orientation="horizontal", and set   android:gravity="left" & android:layout_weight="1" on one and android:gravity="right" & android:layout_weight="1" on the other (yes, the weight is required!)

Note, using layout_toRightOf will give left/right relative positioning but it won't force them to the edge of the screen/parent container.